# Best Case for Bubble Sort

Tags: algorithm, bubble-sort

I want to know what will be the best case for a bubble sort ? There may be a case wherein there may be no swapping for the say last 2 passes for example. I'm doing my program in C language. 
Suppose i have an array of 5 elements and i give the elements as 1 2 5 4 3 then there would be no change in the last 2 passes?

Comment: The best case would be if the list were already sorted but I don't think that's what you're asking. Could you be more specific?

Comment: I also don't see what this has to do with C#

Answer (score 34):

Best case scenario is one pass.  The list would already be sorted.
No swap = done.

Comment: @Jon Without specifying the algorithm how could you tell about the best case complexity. I could see a lots of bubble sort implementations

Comment: @user567879 Regardless of the bubble sort implementation, at least one full pass is required to ensure the list is sorted.  Best case is the list is sorted, and will require a single pass to verify this.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: @Jon If use a bubble sort like this (first algorithm) http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Bubble_sort. The best case complexity is O(n^2) ?

Comment: @user567879 n^2 would be your worst case.  Think about what happens when a bubble sort is run.  IF your list is already sorted, it will run through your list once for each item.  BEST CASE is n (number of items in the collection), as a bubble sort will require checking each item once.

Answer (score 28):

Best Case: The best case would be if the list were already sorted. 
a)  there will be comparisons as it is but no exchanges and execution time is in O(n2) 
b)  But if we keep a track of exchanges in each pass and terminate the program checking if no exchanges. Then the program would require only one pass and max. (n-1) comparisons are required in that single pass and we can say that the complexity is of order of O(n).

Answer (score 12):

Please see [Bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort):

> Bubble sort has worst-case and average
>   complexity both О(n²), where n is the
>   number of items being sorted. There
>   exist many sorting algorithms with
>   substantially better worst-case or
>   average complexity of O(n log n). Even
>   other О(n²) sorting algorithms, such
>   as insertion sort, tend to have better
>   performance than bubble sort.
>   Therefore bubble sort is not a
>   practical sorting algorithm when n is
>   large.
>
> - **Worst case performance**       *O(n²)*
> - **Best case performance**        *O(n)*
> - **Average case performance**     *O(n²)*
> - **Worst case space complexity**  *O(n) total, O(1) auxiliary*
> - **Optimal**                       *No*

Answer (score 12):

There are multiple ways to write the bubble sort algorithm, it seems like over time the algorithm has gotten better, and more efficient. The first bubble sort algorithm I learned is below. The algorithm below Best and Worst Case is O(n^2).

```
BUBBLESORT(A)
1 for i = 1 to A.length - 1
2     for j = A.length downto i + 1
3         if A[j] < A[j - 1]
4             exchange A[j] with A[j - 1]
```

The algorithm that Wikipedia uses (below) seems to be an improvement using a flag to tell if the elements have been swapped or not, which allows the bubble sort algorithm best case to be O(n) instead of O(n^2)

```
    procedure bubbleSort( A : list of sortable items )
    n = length(A)
    repeat 
        swapped = false
        for i = 1 to n-1 inclusive do
            /* if this pair is out of order */
            if A[i-1] > A[i] then
                /* swap them and remember something changed */
                swap( A[i-1], A[i] )
                swapped = true
            end if
        end for
    until not swapped
end procedure
```

Here is a video that helps explain a little bit about the first algorithm in the C programming language:
https://youtu.be/qOpNrqqTsk4

Comment: If, say in some program, earlier bubble sort required all iterations to be done. This swapped = false helps our program to stop anytime so reduces many steps.
well answer.

Answer (score 2):

The best case is when the data is already sorted. Another good case is when there are a tiny number of items to sort - I once used it when my typical list was two items and occasionally went to four.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell if you mean

1. What is the best case algorithmic complexity of the bubble sort, in which case C# makes no difference, the answer is `O(`*n*`)` for an already sorted input.
2. When, if ever, you should consider using a bubble sort.

In the latter case, you don't, because for the small cases the [Shell sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_sort) and [Insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) will both outperform it. Some of the best performing sorting routines I've seen are hybrids Quick Sort that use a Shell Sort for "small" sections of the array.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible for a bubble sort not to swap for two passes.

A pass without swapping means the list is already sorted.

Answer (score 0):

A bubble sort is rarely your best case for doing a sort. It is exceptionally slow and inefficient. Many other sorting algorithms are faster. For example, you may consider using something like a QuickSort.

The fastest sorting algorithm I am aware of was developed by Steffan Nilsson and is described in the following article.

http://www.ddj.com/architect/184404062;jsessionid=VWL2QD1NWIEIJQE1GHOSKHWATMY32JVN?_requestid=396640

If you just want to know how to implement a bubble sort, you can find a good article here.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: You may want to note that the very fastest sorts are very often application-specific, though almost all applications are insensitive to that benefit next to the expense of optimizing beyond a well-written general purpose (library) algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

either wikipedia or i'm wrong but for me best case and worst case are both O(n2) this is
from the book Introduction to Algorithms

```
BUBBLESORT(A)
1 for i = 1 to A.length - 1
2     for j = A.length downto i + 1
3         if A[j] < A[j - 1]
4             exchange A[j] with A[j - 1]
```

so regardles of whether the array is sorted or not there is no one pass
becoz even if line 4 is skipped line 2 and 3 are executed propotionally
to n2 times

edit:
i think i got it wikipedia are right after all but one has to modify the
algorithm by adding let's say boolean variable is_exchange setting it to false before entering the second loop and if it's false again after exiting the loop then we are done and in that case time will be O(n) becoz second loop is executed n times